# How to us a LIKE against an IN or list in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, search, where-clause

I have a comma delimited string of keywords which I have successfully transformed into a list using a function that takes a `@String` and returns a TABLE(Value varchar(30))

I can now use this list in a where clause like follows:

```
SELECT project.*
FROM Projects project 
WHERE project.title IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.ParamsToList('.net,test'))
```

This matches where project.title is exactly (equal to) any one of the keywords (.net or test).

What I need is to match where title is `LIKE '%' + any-keyword + '%'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is like this:

```
SELECT project.*
FROM Projects project 
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM dbo.ParamsToList('.net,test') x 
        WHERE project.title LIKE '%' + x.value + '%'
    )
```

This approach will mean you don't get the same project returned multiple times, if the project matches multiple values from the params list.

Comment: Ah, now that I should have thought of. Thanks, great help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `JOINING` the results of the function like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT project.*
FROM   Projects project
       INNER JOIN dbo.ParamsToList('.net,test') pl ON project.title LIKE '%' + pl.Value + '%'
```

Comment: While this would work, unfortunately i'm in a more complex context where such a join would mess up my results. Thanks! The answer by AdaTheDev below seems to fit my needs

Comment: Try to avoid using `JOIN` as a filter predicate. For one, it makes the code more self-explanatory to use `EXISTS`, but also it may multiply the results. In this case when there are records that match both entries.

Comment: @GertArnold - funny, I find myself having more trouble reading `EXISTS` than `JOIN`. Probably what I got exposed to first. The `DISTINCT` would take care of the multiple results. Haven't tested it but I do assume the `EXISTS` clause is less overhead.

Comment: It's not entirely my personal preference. There are [good reason for favoring EXISTS in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7082449/861716). Often `DISTINCT` is a patch for duplications that could have been prevented.

Comment: @GertArnold - according to that answer the main reason seems to be performance. As the author states: `JOIN syntax is easier to read and clearer normally as well.`.