# What is the diffrence between .where() and .whereExists() in knex.js?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I believe it is the same question as if asking what is the difference between WHERE and WHERE EXIST ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.where()` creates a `WHERE` clause, as in:

```
select `id` from `users` where `first_name` = 'Test' and `last_name` = 'User'
```

This clause is used to begin the conditional portion of a query.

`.whereExists()` creates a `WHERE EXISTS` clause, as in:

```
select * from `users` where exists (select * from `accounts` where users.account_id = accounts.id)
```

This clause tests for existence of rows in the subquery.  In some cases, it is faster than using a `JOIN`, as it does not join the entire table to the higher-level table (in the `FROM` clause).  More information at [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082449/exists-vs-join-and-use-of-exists-clause)

(These example queries were taken from the [knex website](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereExists))

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)